# Improper Integral: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$

Tags: calculus

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$

I u-subed, integrated, and then applied the limit. I am not to sure if this is illegal calculus.

Nonetheless, going with the thought of what I've done is okay:

Does infinity under a radical sign plus the one amount to infinity?

[image]

Comment: What you've done is acceptable. The integral diverges.

Comment: Yes, "infinity under a radical sign plus one" is still infinity.

Comment: The integral diverges.  And there was a miscue in the calculation.  For $u=1+x^3$, we have $du=3x^2\,dx$, not $2x^2\,dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is mostly fine; the conclusion is correct, but the only mistake occurs with calculating $du$. Putting $u=x^3+1$ gives $du=3x^2$, not $2x^2$.

Comment: And that error does flow through ... but the integral diverges, so ...

Comment: @Dr.MV: Which is why I mention the conclusion is correct. If the student isn't aware of his mistake, it could lead to incorrect conclusions later on (e.g., if an integral converges and he used this "rule" of differentiation, he would get an incorrect value and perhaps not understand why).

Comment: Yes;  I wasn't being critical of your answer.  I was only clarifying a very important issue.  +1 for your answer

Comment: @Dr.MV: I see; I'm sorry for the misinterpretation. I thought you meant to imply that because the mistake didn't affect his answer, it was negligible. Also, I just read your comment under the OP. When I first read it, there was only, "The integral diverges." which is why I wanted to post this (I don't want you to feel like I was taking credit for your statement).

Comment: Not at all.  You posted a solid answer.  I thought it might be enhanced by explicitly stating that the integral is a divergent improper integral.  If we truncate the upper limit, then ...